# Regex pattern only unlimited numbers with max 2 digits after the comma

Tags: c#, regex

Hei Guys

I got the regex for my software and it works. I only need the pattern that I will write between (" ") these. Thank you guys

The seperator should be `a ,` or `a .`

Comment: Perhaps you can provide sample inputs and expected outputs to help

Comment: Do you know the pattern? That would help alot, cause I could just fill it in and it would work :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: '\d' for number, '\d+'for more numbers before ',' ...

```
  \d+(,\d\d?)?
```

or

```
  \d+(,\d{1,2})?
```